# Why is ListCellRenderer called when setSelectedItem() is used?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, listcellrenderer

I have a [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) that is intended to be used to select a [Font](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html). To allow for a preview of the font when the user is making a selection I have written a custom [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html):

```
public class FontListCellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer<String>{
    private ListCellRenderer<Object> defaultRenderer;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public FontListCellRenderer(){
        this.defaultRenderer = (ListCellRenderer<Object>) new JComboBox<Object>().getRenderer();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends String> list,
            String value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Component returnVal = this.defaultRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        returnVal.setFont(new Font((String) value, returnVal.getFont().getStyle(), returnVal.getFont().getSize()));
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

In using this however I noticed a drastic performance hit when initializing my [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) with this [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html). Upon further investigation I discovered that my [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) was being called for many fonts when I set the default value for my item with [setSelectedItem()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedItem%28java.lang.Object%29).

For now I have changed my code to set the [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) last but I would like to know why is this happening? Even if my item were on the screen (which it is not yet) the [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) does not render the selected item as it is shown idly in the [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html). Even if it was, why is it being called for non-selected items?

Comment: Because one of the responsibilities of the render is to highlight the selection.

Comment: @MadProgrammer It still begs the question of why is this happening now? The renderer will be called again when a layout is performed so calling it at this time simply wastes cycles. Is this just a case of poor optimization of the swing library?

Comment: Each time the component is resized, it needs to re-render its content...seems to make sense. You can use setPrototypeCellValue which will stop the JList from running through all the values to calculate the width and height, but this is only going to work if the height (in particular) of all the elements is the same. You'll also want to know the length of the longest strong, but given the fact that you're using variable width fonts, this is going to cause you issues...this should highlight some of the reasons why JList works the way it does...

Comment: You could work out an optimal maximum length to set the cell width to ahead of time. Could be a bit of work/trial and error, but would prevent said resizing during usage?